# Trying to break a data model

Tags: ms-access, data-modeling, datamodel

I have been designing a data model and i have been told that it is incorrect and i have to try and "break it". I have been adding a lot of data in and i still cant break it. Im not to sure which relationship is wrong i was thinking the customer details to payment details but i couldnt change it so now im not to sure at all. Can anyone help me and possible see what might be wrong with the data model i have created. Any help is much appreciated. [Data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMgmA.jpg)

Comment: Given the major components of Vehicles, Customers and Chauffeurs, look at the way some of your other tables are related. Vehicle Inspections is fine because it only relates to Vehicles. Chauffeurs is probably ok, but an argument can be made that Customers and Chauffeurs share similar info, so maybe could be in the same table. Booking is fine. Now, I do have a problem with Payment details and Invoice. Seems there needs to be more info about the Invoice (i.e. Paid, Date paid, Amount Paid, Payment method, etc.) ... see more in next comment...

Comment: ... continued ... and I feel Payments needs to be related to Invoices. Plus the fact that you have a one-to many relationship of Invoice to Booking. This means you can't enter a Booking until you have an Invoice. Is that the business rule? What if someone makes multiple payments… do you need to handle that? You can infer the customer name and address for the Invoice by its relationship with Booking so I will accept that.

Comment: I agree with Wayne - your Payment Details table, lacks uniqueness, and card number should not be the the PK. A "Payment ID" in Payment Details, with a matching FK (Invoice Number) from Invoice, would be more dynamic. Also, "First Name/Last Name" in Booking seems a little redundant, if not ambiguous - who's name? Driver/Customer? If either, the ID field already covers both.

Another note, you probably shouldn't be storing detailed private customer card information in a database - if you are compromised, and they are robbed, you are liable.

Comment: In my data model i dont actually need to be able to receive payments just to be able to hold a customers payment information and be able to send them a bill of what they owe. Your right about the invoice, i would like to be able to create an invoice without having to create one in the invoice table first. What primary key should payment information have if not card number ??

Comment: PK for Payment could be 'PayID Autonumber'. If you must save credit card info, then I would at least encrypt it. Then if it's encrypted, you really don't want that as your PK.
What if someone books, then cancels? Looks like you would need to delete the Booking (else you have an Invoice hanging around); would you then delete the Customer? I suggest a 'status' field in Booking. If you don't need to track receipt of payments, how will you ever know who has paid their invoice? It can get very messy if you track payments in a different system.